# Instalar o composer no Windows 2012

Tags: apache, composer, php-7

Meu sistema operacional tem dois Apaches rodando dois phps (5 e 7.1 respectivamente).
Estou tentando instalar o composer para o PHP7, mas está dando a seguinte mensagem:

> The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly: C:\PHP7\php.exe
>
> The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\PHP5\php.ini
>
> A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the
>   'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.

Se eu digito no localhost:81 que é porta para o php7 ele funciona normal trazendo o phpinfo, mas no composer dá erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu tento pela linha de comando é como se o openssl não estivesse ativado, mas está

Dá a seguinte mensagem ao tentar o comando abaixo:

php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"

> Warning: copy(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget
>   to enable it when you configured PHP?

Comment: Apague a instalação do php5

Comment: Mas eu preciso dos dois

Comment: Mas mesmo assim, deu certo, recortei a pasta do PHP5 para outra e tentei novamente e deu certo então voltei novamente a pasta do PHP5, e funcionou normalmente, valeu

Comment: Pelo que entendo você necessita forçar a chamada ao php.ini do php 7, deverá ter uma variavel de ambiente definida com a instalação do php5. Verifique as variaveis de ambiente

Comment: mas estava justamente nas variaveis de ambiente o php7

Comment: @lazyFox adicione seu comentário como resposta a de `Apague a instalação do php5`

Comment: Um bocada fraca a resposta, mas pronto fica registada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apague a instalação do php5, existe um conflicto na chamada do php.ini

Answer (score 1):

Não precisa apagar o php5, fora que se apagar então você não vai conseguir testar no seu Apache com ele.

O problema é que **provavelmente** ambas versões do PHP estão na variável `PATH` de *variáveis de ambiente* e/ou *variáveis de usuário*, exemplo:

> [image: variaveis de ambiente no windows]

Eu pessoalmente recomendo que revise tanto *variáveis de usuário* quanto *variáveis de sistema*, pois se tiver PHP5 e PHP7 ao mesmo vai complicar mesmo.

Então o ideal seria usar somente um ou outro nas variáveis, no caso creio que deseja usar o PHP7, então remova tudo que tiver haver com php5 das *variáveis de usuário* e *variáveis de sistema* (faça o logoff e o logon novamente para ter certeza que irá atualizar tudo).

Comment: Na verdade eu gostaria de usar os dois

Comment: @adventistaam mas isso não irá impedir em nada de usar os dois, vc poderá instalar o composer normalmente para o 7 e ainda ter o php5 no apache, só que o composer vai instalar os pacotes baseados no PHP7.

Comment: mas eu já havia tirado o php5 das variáveis de ambiente

Comment: @adventistaam a não ser que vc queira ter "2 composers", algo como digitar `composer7 update` `composer5 update`

Comment: @adventistaam tem variaveis de ambiente e variaveis de sistema, como eu mostrei na imagem, vc tem que copiar os campos colar no bloco de notas e olhar com calma.

Comment: Ahhh isso nao sabia.. então seriam possivel usar tanto o laravel 5.3 quanto o 5.6?

Comment: @adventistaam se o seu desejo for ter 2 composers, sim mas será um trabalho manual para instalar duas versões, e isso não é a pergunta aqui, creio eu. Então sim, seria possivel instalar 2 composers para versões diferentes do PHP, o que dependeria de algum esforço manual, talvez uma hora eu formule um passo-a-passo para windows.

Comment: @adventistaam a minha resposta aqui já formulada é só para dizer, "não precisa excluir o php5 para usar o composer no php7", pois conforme a outra resposta vc foi obrigado a isto, o que **"independente"** do composer vc teve que fazer e realmente não era algo necessário.

Comment: Concordo com o @Guilherme, apenas é necessário remover a associação a uma instalação para não confundir o "composer". Neste caso a do php5, mas poderá continuar a fazer uso da mesma.